# How do i scale my fitness values? (using PyGAD)

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm, fitness, pygad

As the title says, i want to use fitness scalling methods, such as sigma scalling, for i'm having problems with premature genetic conversion in non-optimal solutions.

I know that PyGAD has a `on_fitness` method that is called after the fitness values for all my individuals are calculated, and think i could use to solve my problem with it, but could not verify. Can i use it for this purpose?

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't know if this is the best way, but here is how I solved my problem.
With the release of PyGAD 2.19, a new constructor option was added, the `fitness_batch_size`. As it's name sujests, you can now pass a batch of individuals at once to one execution of your fitness function, like so:

```
# with fitness_batch_size = None(or 1)

Solution = [2.184, 0,...,3.2819]

# with 1 < fitness_batch_size <= sol_per_pop
Solution = [[2.184, 0,...,3.2819], [1.234, 2.345,..., 5],...,[...]]
```

With this in mind, now to scale my fitness, I have to adjust `fitness_batch_size = sol_per_pop` and generate all fitness values at once. Afterwards, it's matter of passing all values through some kind of scaling and returning this result as my fitness values.

If you know a better way, please post it here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is the best solution. Using the `on_fitness()` function works too but it only costs an additional function call to edit the fitness values.

Comment: So it can actually be done with the <code>on_fitness()</code> huh. I though it wasn't possible due to what i saw in exemples from PyGAD, where it only shows some <code>print()</code> as a result, didn't know you could also return something. Thank you.

Comment: `on_fitness()` does not allow you to return anything. But I mean you can change the latest population fitness there by editing the last_generation_fitness attribute.

Comment: Oh, ok.Thank you for clarifying. Never thought about doing that.